# How to coerce data frame into itemsets or rules for ARules in R

Tags: r, transactions, arules

I have an itemsets object generated by eclat function

```
`items     support count
 [1] {15952188,25783544} 0.008674149  7282
 [2] {15952189,25783543} 0.007541340  6331`
```

I want to put descriptions to these numbers, so I coerce the itemsets object into a data frame and edit the lhs items.

Is there a way to coerce this back into an itemsets object so I can use some of the arules visualizations?

Answer (score -1):

The best way would be to change the labels in the transactions before you mine the itemsets. Look at `? itemLabels`. You can also use `itemLables()` to assign new labels to itemsets (requires the latest version of arules). Here is an example:

```
library(arules)
data("Adult")
fsets <- eclat(Adult, parameter = list(supp = 0.5))

# look at current item labels
itemLabels(fsets)

# replace the labels with the labels + "*"
itemLabels(fsets) <- paste0(itemLabels(fsets), "*")

# look at the new item labels
itemLabels(fsets)
```